# is Thread.Join() a good way to let main thread update GUI while a thread func is working

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have `Main()` function which displays in label the current time. There is a button which calls a function `LoadUserImage()` for reading image files and writing them to database and then showing the result of reading and writing in another label.   While `LoadUserImage()` is running I want the `Main()` function to still display in label the current time. My instructor tells me to put `LoadUserImage()`  in a separate thread and then join it. But on his lectures he tells that `Thread.Join()` makes the main thread kind of pause temporarily The question is: if joining makes the main thread pause then how can it update the GUI in my case?

Comment: Have you looked up the documentation for `Thread.Join`?

Comment: What kind of application is this?  WinForms maybe?  A label being updated continuously in a `Main()` function is probably the wrong approach to start with...

Comment: What GUI framework are you using? You should probably look at async / await

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of Thread.Join() is to make sure that the background thread started previously is stopped properly, but it is not needed for the background thread to work.

In your case, you start the long-running operation in a background thread, and in the main thread proceed with the other activities.  You need to call Thread.Join() only at the end, when the main thread has already finished its activity.  If at that point the background thread had terminated already, Thread.Join() will return right away, while if the background thread is still busy, it will block (in the main thread) until the background thread has finished.  This is the way to make sure an app is not exiting until operations are active in the background.

I suppose in your Main() (running in the main thread) you have some loop which periodically updates some UI.  This loop has some exit condition (e.g. by reacting to pressing Enter in a Console.ReadLine(), or a Ctrl-C handler).  Once the loop is exited, it can call Thread.Join().

If proper exit is not implemented at all in your sample program (which is not so nice, but usual in such sample program), then you don't have to call Thread.Join() at all!  When the process exits, all threads disappear anyways.